# The difference between action object and target in django-activity-stream

Tags: django, django-activity-stream

With **django-activity-stream** one can create activity streams (what were the latest things done?) like in Facebook, Twitter, or any other social network.

What is the difference and what are the use cases of **action object** and **target** there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of [http://activitystrea.ms/](http://activitystrea.ms) :

> **[Object]** describes the primary object of the activity. For instance, in the activity, "John saved a movie to his wishlist", the object of the activity is "movie".
>
> **[Target]** describes the target of the activity. The precise meaning of the activity's target is dependent on the activities verb, but will often be the object the English preposition "to". For instance, in the activity, "John saved a movie to his wishlist", the target of the activity is "wishlist".

Think of it as an english sentence :

```
 Actor   Verb       Object       Target
_________________________________________________________ 
 Paul  | uploaded | an artwork | to his collection
 Jane  | added    | an event   | to her personal calendar
 Aidas | asked    | a question | on django discussion
```

Comment: How would it be in this case:
__John (actor) recommended (verb) “The Matrix” (target) to Mary (object)__
or
__John (actor) recommended (verb) “The Matrix” (object) to Mary (target)__?

Comment: Regarding the definition of target, I would clearly go for the second one.